# How do I change what a pointer passed to a function is pointing to from within the function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a function that you pass a pointer to a list (MList) to

```
int ml_add(MList **ml, MEntry *me){
    //I need to create new MList here
    //and have *ml point to my new list
}
```

In the ml_add function I need to create a new MList, and have the function argument 'MList **ml' point towards my new list and discard the old list that ml was pointing to. There is a separate function outside this one that has an Mlist and is adding things to it using this ml_add function. Inside ml_add I need to create a new list and have the calling function pass in the new list when it calls ml_add from then on. Is this possible?

I am unsure if

```
*ml = newList;
```

is working

Comment: Have you tried it? And yes, that will work (provided you pass a correct and valid pointer as argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Try someting like this:

```
int ml_add(MList **ml, MEntry *me){
    //I need to create new MList here
    //and have *ml point to my new list

    MList * newList = malloc(sizeof(MList));

    // TODO: check malloc return value, 
    //       add references between newList and me as well as between newList and ml.

    *ml = newList;

    // return a meaningful value
}
```

Comment: Always test the result of `malloc` !